# How can I save each input value of a jquery keyup() in MySQL database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am creating a study for my university and want to save each input value a user types in a password field into a database.

For example: 
A user types "hello" as a password. I want to save 'h', 'he', 'hel', 'hell' and at least 'hello'. If he deletes a character like the last one I want to save this as well: 'hell'.

Currently I am saving the last value 'hello' like this:

**startpage.php:**

```
<form action="?atn=validatePassword" method="post" class="form mg_top">
   <label id="enterPW" for="inp_list_generatedPassword">Select or enter Password:</label>
   <input id="inp_list_generatedPassword" name="password" value="" type='password' class="form-control talign_center input" placeholder="Select or enter password">
</form>
```

**ViewController.php:**

```
private function validatePassword(){        
  $password = $_POST["password"];
}
```

To get the inputs I have a js file where I am using the keyup event:

**startpage.js:**

```
$('#inp_list_generatedPassword').keyup(function() {
var input = this.value;
$('#output').val(input);
$.ajax({
    url: "startpage.php",
    data: {
        'keyValue' : input
    },
    dataType: 'json',
   });
});
```

In the ViewController.php I am adding this line `$currentPW = $_GET["keyValue"];`
But it doesn't work. I am getting an error: *Undefined index: keyValue in ViewController.php*

In addition this won't save each input. It just saves the last entered string when the button is pressed: `<button id="matchPassword" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Submit</button>`

How can I save all steps? And is there a mistake in my code or rather in the Ajax call?

Comment: This is going to hammer your database and your network I/O. Why do you want to save for every single keypress? I would think you'd want to start a save countdown timer and reset it on every keypress. When they stop pressing keys the timer will finish instead of being reset and trigger a save. http://codetunnel.io/how-to-implement-autosave-in-your-web-app/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, this will give your database an immense overload if someone types really weird stuff.

You need to use a cache in your PHP-Script, but that is not really part of the Question.

**To the Solution:**

I tried it and it worked with this:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#inp_list_generatedPassword', function() {
    var input = this.value;
    $('#output').text(input);
});
```

Seeing here: https://jsfiddle.net/cj1367eo/

Now you can use your "input" variable just as you want.
I also would prefer using "$.post" as seen here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Attention, untested code:

```
$.post( "api.php", { data: input } );
```

Now you can use the $_POST["data"] to get your input.

**Additional Information:**

But as i told before: **Use a cache!**

Else your system can get in real trouble.

It is really enough to use a global PHP variable that you write every N Minutes or Entries into your database.

Comment: Thank you Mijago. My problem is the "$.post" demand. It is not working. maybe I use the wrong path? This is the path of my js file: "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mySurvey3/web/js/views/startpage/startpage.js "
and this of my php file to which I want to send the input: "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mySurvey3/webcontroller/ViewController.php". What do i have to write in $.post( "?.php", { data: input } );

and how do I use a cache? I've never done something like this before....

Comment: If  /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ is the basepath you use (you call in the browser http://localhost/mySurvey3 or so), try /mySurvey3/webcontroller/ViewController.ph‌​p